# Detect if there was an sql injection attack by parsing access logs or HTTP params. PHP Websites

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

As most programmers I try to program my applications in the safest way possible but this we know that does not guarantee security at 100%. Therefore I think it is also appropriate to have methods to monitor if we may be being attacked. So this is my question.

(My websites are made with **PHP and MySQL**)

In the case of SQL injection I think this can be done in two ways, but if there are other ways I would also like to know them.

- **Parsing access/error logs**. Does anyone have or know a script that adequately analyzes the access logs (apache) to detect possible attacks? And notify to the administrator automatically with all details.
- **Analyze HTTP params at real time**. It would be a script that analyzes in real time the content passed by GET / POSt and notify (e.g. via email) to the administrator of the website

For example, I do not know much about SQLi attacks but **I think it's common for the 'SELECT', 'UINON',...(Others?) strings to appear in query strings and params**.

In this way we can analyze the attack and see if it succeeds or not, and then take the consequent actions.

Thanks for your attention!

**Edited: Simple bash script**

**I have made a simple system for analyzing the Apache access_log** files and communicate results by email. Which is detailed in this question:
[Linux bash to iterate over apache access_log files and send mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180232/linux-bash-to-iterate-over-apache-access-log-files-and-send-mail)

**In addition, another one using AWK**. The only one resource I've found related about that:
https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/248420-sql-injection-detection.html
(But I have not been able to make it runs in my case)

Comment: The good news: you invented something that is worth loads of money. The bad news: others did too, and they are making loads of money. :)
You can find products for security log analysis, and also there is [RASP](https://techbeacon.com/what-runtime-application-self-protection-rasp), or [WAFs](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall) among many related technologies.

Comment: I get "attacked" like this all the time... but it never gets the would-be attackers anywhere, because there is simply no excuse to write code that is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Zero tolerance for string concatenation/interpolation into queries, including escaping and sanitizing. Zero tolerance for enabling multi-query support. Use prepared statements always and everywhere and SQLi becomes something other people have to worry about, not you.  The problem really should have been relegated to being one of academic interest only, by now.

Comment: Yes, before asking I've seen that there were commercial options. But my question is based on whether someone knows or wants something to do that or give indications of things we can do without investing too much time that can be effective, because I would implement them.

I believe that an important aspect in security is to monitor and generate warnings (not only implement with security measures and assume that everything is OK).

It's easy to add vulnerable code to a website throughout your life, even if you have a lot of security knowledge.

Comment: Take a look at the access logs is scary. Constantly attempts of attack of all type, mainly SQLi instructions. Many times I use those REQUEST on the web to see the effect they have been able to produce.
This is the reality. Constantly thousands of robots trying to attack.
Let's wait a little more to someone that had done about it and want share their script or knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Oh boy.

Alright, where to start?

For starters, remember that bad hackers are usually financially motivated. You know your website has been injected if you wake up one morning to a red error message from Chrome or Firefox, and you open it anyway to find that your website is now among the more popular places to find free cruises and viagra online.

Sites that score well with SEO are more likely to be hacked than sites that do not. More users means more exposure. Password protected sites don't get hacked as often, but the password protection itself does not necessarily mean any added security. If you're vulnerable, you're vulnerable, and you need to be on top of it.

First and foremost, remember to filter your variables. Never trust anything that comes in from a browser. **IT'S ALL SUSPECT.** That's means filtering anything that counts as a super global, GET POST, REQUEST, etc. I wouldn't even trust sessions, honestly. Filter it all. More on this can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Something else to think about is file uploading. Bad guys love uploading files, and taking over your server. Most common method is exploit files disguised as images. You're going to want to resample every image that comes in. GD Works, but I like Imagick better, personally, more options. More on that here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php You're also going to want to make sure that your site can't upload images or any other type of file from pages that you don't explicitly designate as form or upload pages. You would be shocked how often I see sites that can upload from the index, it's insane.

Another method you can deploy for this, is use your php ini to set a global include, and open up any file in a $_FILES array that comes in. Open up the first million spaces in the file, and scan it for php reserved words, and unix shell scripting. If you find one, kill the upload, exit or die, whatever you like to do there.

Apache has a setting for forensic logs. Forensic logs will capture all GET and POST stuff, but the issue with it, and the reason it's not exposed by default is that your log get big, and quickly. You can read up on it here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_forensic.html

Lastly, you're going to want to evaluate your site for injection vulnerabilities and cross site scripting. Cross site scripting isn't the issue it once was, given the way browsers are constructed these days. All those little details that make life harder for us as a developers actually make us more secure.

But you do want to check for SQL vulnerabilities, especially if you're writing code from scratch. There are a couple reasonably solid plugins for Chrome that make pen testing a little easier.

Hackbar: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hackbar/ejljggkpbkchhfcplgpaegmbfhenekdc?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

HackTab: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hack-tab-web-security-tes/nipgnhajbnocidffkedmkbclbihbalag?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

For Firefox, there's scrippy
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrippy/?src=search

Hope that helps.
Good luck.

Comment: `Sites that score well with SEO are more likely to be hacked than sites that do not. More users means more exposure.`

The majority of attacks are made by robots that seek all kinds of vulnerability, information about the website etc. So all the websites are objective But we can use those attacks as a security audit. It we are waiting for notices and we check what could happened in the attack.

Thank you very much for all these safety notes. Without a doubt, of great value.

Comment: Right on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore I think it is also appropriate to have methods to monitor if we may be being attacked.

The biggest waste of time ever.

ANY site gets "attacked" 100% of time. There are freely avalable scripts that allow any stupid schoolboy to scan whole internet, probing sites just by chance. You'll grow bored the very next day after scouring these logs of your detection system.

In your place I would invest in the protection. Other vectors than you could think of. For examle, all recent breakings I was a vitness of were performed by means of stealing ftp passwords stored on the webmaster's PC. And I can assure you that there are much more attack vectors than a blunt SQL injection. Which is a simplest thing to protect from, with   [only two simple rules to follow](https://phpdelusions.net/top#escaping):

- Any variable data literal (i.e. a string or a number) should be substituted with a parameter, whereas actual value should be sent to the query separately, through bind/execute process.
- All other query parts that happen to be added through a variable, should be explicitly filtered through a hardcoded list of allowed values.