# Linux bash to iterate over apache access_log files and send mail

Tags: linux, bash, shell, security, sql-injection

I need a linux bash script which send me an email if any results appear in searches made in the apache logs.

I have a very simple method (sentence) to look into SQL Injection attacks, which simply searches for some keywords used in SQLi. Is this:

```
#tail -50000 /var/vhosts/site.com/logs/access_log | egrep -i "select%20|union%20|'|1=1"
```

So now I would like to be able to launch it in several access_log (for each website - virtual host I have) and send me an email in case of finding results.

**In a schematic way:**

I have the apache access_log files, one for each virtual host:

```
/var/vhosts/website_1/access_log
/var/vhosts/website_2/access_log
etc...
```

And the scheme of the bash process I'm talking:

```
for each access_log file (one by virtual host)
    result = tail -50000 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/logs/access_log | egrep -i "select%20|union%20|'|1=1"
    if any line appear in the result then
        send mail(myemail@site.com, 'Warning!: Possible attack in virtual_host_i')
end;
```

Does anyone know how to implement this script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hover your mouse over the `batch-file` tag.

Comment: I've replaced the batch-file tag with bash and shell tags. I cannot say for sure if you're using the bash shell, so you may wish to replace the bash tag with your shell of choice.

Comment: Sorry I have mistaken the terms, in any case I think the question is relevant and well posed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a good plan, just need to code it.
Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(ls /var/vhosts/*/access_log);  do 
  result=""   #reset the result variable
  result=$(tail -50000 "${file}" | egrep -i "(select )|(union )|'|(1=1)")
  if [[ ! -z $result ]]; then
    echo "file ${file} contains suspicious lines:"
    echo $result
    # or enter your command for mailing the result
    # for example:
    # echo ${result} | mail -s ${file} youremail@site.com
    # check man page for your mail command!
  fi
done
```

Comment: What's wrong with a tested, working answer? I don't understand. A word of explanation of down vote would be appreciated.

Comment: That's right, I agree that whoever gives a negative vote should give a clarification about it that helps to improve who has done something wrong.
It's a usual bad behaivor here. But at least, my vote you already have it, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I would like to see if you can add in the script, the sending of the alert email with the data shown by the 'echoes'. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding sending an e-mail - it is not related to bash or this script, it depends on what you have installed or plan to install. But you have the important data in variables `$file` and `$result`, which you can pass to the sending command as parameters.

Comment: I have proved to add this: `${result} | mail -s ${file} myemail@site.com` in the commented line and it sends the email but with null mesasge body... any idea?

Comment: What kind of `mail` do you use? From what package? Check the man page for it.

Comment: Centos 7. I have already solved it. Missing to include the result var in the echo: `echo{$result}` I'm going to include that in your response and finish the question. Thanks